# cannot convert sourcetype 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to target type 'string'

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In VisualStudio 2008 I get the following error on my linq query:

cannot convert sourcetype 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to target type 'string'

This is the query:

```
  var query = (from c in model.ITEMLIST
               select new ItemList
                        {
                          LineNo = c.LINE_NO,
                          SupplierName = from s in model.VENDOR where s.ID == c.ID_VENDOR select s.NAME
                                                     });
```

If I run the same query in LinqPad it returns with success the expected result

I am using LinqToEntity for this. 
In another project where I am using LinqToSql I have a similar query which runs fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
SupplierName = from s in model.VENDOR where s.ID == c.ID_VENDOR select s.NAME
```

`SupplierName` is a `string` but the right hand side is a query. Try assigning the only result in the query instead.

```
SupplierName = 
    (from s in model.VENDOR where s.ID == c.ID_VENDOR select s.NAME).Single()
```

---

or, in the style I prefer

```
SupplierName = model.VENDOR.Single(v => v.ID == c.ID_VENDOR).NAME;
```